# Include unicode from emoji-regex npm library in this regex /^[\w ]+$/ pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, emoji

I want a regex that matches English letters, numbers, spaces and all emojis basically (including stuff like ‍️)
There is https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-regex but I don't know how to include it in my regex `/^[\w ]+$/` which only matches letters, numbers (a-z, A-Z, 0-9) and white spaces.

this "hello ‍️" should match.

this "❤" should match.

this "hello 123" should match.

this "‍️!" should not match (also applies to any other special or non-English characters)

I also tried `/^[\w\p{Emoji} ]+$/u` but it doesn't work for more complex cases like ‍️

Comment: Are you using node.js?

Comment: yes i am using node.js

Comment: Try specifying `v ` flag instead of `u` Then javascript should support emojis

Comment: you mean `/^[\w\p{Emoji} ]+$/v.test('‍️')`? its still returning false

Answer (score 0):

You can use emojiRegex and also include your regex like this.

```
import emojiRegex from 'emoji-regex';
export function MatchesCombinedRegex(input) {
const yourRegex = /^[\w ]+$/;
const emojis = Array.from(input.match(emojiRegex) || []).join('');
const englishAndNumbers = input.match(yourRegex) || [];
const combinedResult = emojis + englishAndNumbers.join('');
return input === combinedResult;
```

}

and check which input matches .

```
 console.log(MatchesCombinedRegex("hello :no_mouth:"));   // should match
console.log(MatchesCombinedRegex(":heart:"));             // should match
console.log(MatchesCombinedRegex("hello 123"));      // should match
console.log(MatchesCombinedRegex(":no_mouth:!"));
```

Comment: not working as expected.